# Image Filter gives varying results for similar images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagefilter

I am experimenting with custom kernels to extract border lines in given images.

The filter I am using is `np.array([[-2, -1, 0], [-1, 10, 1], [0, 1, 2]])`.
For the given set of images which are of a similar nature, the code generates results where sometimes the hatchings are present whereas absent for other images.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening. I have read about custom filters and how filters work but it does not solve my issue.

**The code is as follows:**

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np 

im_name = sys.argv[1]#give path to the image

im = cv2.imread(im_name, 0)

im_copy = im.copy()

#create custom filter

my_filter = np.array([[-2, -1, 0], [-1, 10, 1], [0, 1, 2]])

dst = cv2.filter2D(im, -1, my_filter)

cv2.imshow("test", im)
cv2.imshow("check", dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Picture `1` and `2` show deviant result, rest of the pictures show expected
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HDdr.jpg)